# No option to enable duplicate message detection

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm trying to create a new Azure Service Bus Queue in Azure Portal.
I also need to enable duplicate message detection, while creating I don't see any such option.
Am i missing anything here?
[image]

Comment: You might have created it with basic Pricing tier. Enabling duplicate message detection is not available in Basic plan.

Comment: I have created a Service bus with premium pricing tier and I have an option to enable duplicate message detection. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxDeM.png)

Comment: Thanks, this really helped! I'm pretty new to Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I have created `Azure service bus` with basic plan, even I don't find option to `Enable duplicate detection` .

***Service Bus with Basic Plan***

[image]

Whereas you can see the option available in other plans(Standard , Premium)

Option is available in Standard and Premium plan.

***Option in Premium Plan***

[image]